# dockerizing node project Cannot find module '/controllers/app.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express

I'm trying to dockerize Node.js application, here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /controllers

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV PORT=8080

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1029
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/controllers/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I have tried to change the workdir many times but it did not work.
How would I go about this?

Comment: it seems you didn't copy `app.js` into the container